# how to cancel pop up audio in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, popup

hello I'm new to code and javascript I'm creating a clock with timer. the countdown is done well with an alarm and a pop up when the timer reaches zero. only I can't turn off the alarm when I close the pop up it opens in a loop. i need help please

```
let departInput = document.querySelector('#times');
let subButton = document.querySelector('#sub')


subButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  let temps = (departInput.value)*60;
  var timerElement = document.getElementById("MyTimerDisplay")
  setInterval(() => {
  let minutes = parseInt(temps / 60, 10)
  let secondes = parseInt(temps % 60, 10)

  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes
  secondes = secondes < 10 ? "0" + secondes : secondes

  timerElement.innerText = `${minutes}:${secondes}`
  temps = temps <= 0 ? 0 : temps - 1
  if(minutes == 0 && secondes == 0){
    var snd = new Audio('clock.mp3');
    snd.play();
    alert("cest l'heure")

    }
  }, 1000)

});
```

Comment: here is my html

Answer (score 0):

To address the problem you are having you should call `clearTimer()` when the alarm rings so that its callback won't be running again and again each second even after the condition to break was met.

Here's a working example to show the point:

```js
let departInput = document.querySelector('#times');
let subButton = document.querySelector('#sub')

subButton.addEventListener('click', event => {

  //decides how many minutes before the alarm rings
  let minutesToAlarm = parseInt(departInput.value);
  //initializes elapsedSeconds
  let elapsedSeconds = minutesToAlarm*60;
  
  var timerElement = document.getElementById("MyTimerDisplay");
  
  var myTimer = setInterval(() => {
  
    //converts elapsedSeconds in mm:ss format and refresh the ui
    let minutes = Math.floor(elapsedSeconds/60);
    let secondes = elapsedSeconds % 60;
    timerElement.innerText = `${minutes}:${secondes}`
    
    //decrement elapsedSeconds by 1 
    elapsedSeconds--;
    
    if(elapsedSeconds === 0){
      /*
       * Part muted because there's no reference to clock.mp3
       *
      var snd = new Audio('clock.mp3');
      snd.play();
      */
      alert("cest l'heure");

      //here clears the timer so that the callback
      //won't be running again anymore
      clearTimeout(myTimer);
    }
  }
  , 1000);
});
```

```css
#sub{
  border: solid 1px black;
  min-width: 5em;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#MyTimerDisplay{
  border: dashed 4px darkgray;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<input id="times" type="text" placeholder="departInput"/>
<button id="sub">clickme</button>

<div id="MyTimerDisplay">#times</div>
```